# How to set a Behavior property of a TextBox within a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox, user-controls, behavior

I have a `UserControl` containing a `TextBox`, published by a property "_TextBox".
How can I set a property of an existing `TextBox` `Behavior`?

```
xmlns:WpfUC="clr-namespace:MyLib.WpfUserControls;assembly=MyAssembly"
xmlns:WpfBH="clr-namespace:MyLib.WpfBehaviors;assembly=MyAssembly"

<!--This is not compiling. Error message: Namespace prefix "_TextBox.WpfBH" not defined.-->
<WpfUC:MyUserControl _TextBox.WpfBH:MyTextBoxBehavior.MyProperty="MyValue" />
```

Comment: Why are you prefixing the namespace with `_TextBox`. What does "published by a property <X>" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, you don't need the `_TextBox.` part.

```
<WpfUC:MyUserControl WpfBH:MyTextBoxBehavior.MyProperty="MyValue" />
```

You have the xml namespace imported called `WpfBH` which maps to a namespace in your code called `MyLib.WpfBehaviors` in `MyAssembly`.

That means there should be a class somewhere in your code which looks like the following:

```
namespace MyLib.WpfBehaviors
{
    public class MyTextBoxBehavior
    {
        // Attached property called MyProperty
    }
}
```

Comment: If I omit the "_TextBox" part the code compiles, but the behavior is not applied. "_TextBox" is a public property inside the `UserControl` that returns the `TextBox`. But the behavior is working if I use a `TextBox` only: `<TextBox WpfBH:MyTextBoxBehavior.MyProperty="MyValue" />`

Comment: @Pollitzer Have a look at the `Grid` and it's attached properties `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column`.